# If a function has an infinite amount of automorphisms would that imply that it is periodic?

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, periodic-functions, automorphism-group

Let $\phi(x)$ be continuous and differentiable everywhere and its automorphisms be bijections $\gamma_{n}$ such that $\phi(\gamma_{n}(x))=\phi(x)$. If the order of $Aut(\phi)$ is infinite, would that mean that $\phi(x)$ is periodic?

I can think of an example of the top of my head: $\phi(x)=sin(x)$ with automorphisms of the form $\gamma_{n}(x)=x+2\pi n$. Could this be applied to any general function $\phi$?

Comment: What is, in this case, an automorphism of $\phi$? A diffeomorphism $\gamma$ of the domain of $\phi$ such that $\phi \circ \gamma = \phi$?

Comment: Yes, the [pdf](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT.pdf) that im reading describes it as a bijection $\alpha$ such that $\phi(\alpha x)=\phi(x)$

Comment: If there are no continuity requirements on $\alpha$, it would suffice that some value is attained by $\phi$ infinitely often.

Comment: If we don't have any further condition on $\gamma$, then it's wrong. Let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x^2$. Then for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ the function $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \gamma(x) = -x$ for $x \in \{a, -a\}$ and $\gamma(x) = x$ for $x \notin \{a, -a\}$ is such an automorphism.

Comment: How would $\phi(x)=x^2$ have an infinite amount of automorphisms?

Comment: I gave you the automorphisms according to your definition. You get an automorphism for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$ as I wrote above. Hence infinitely many.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Because of the 5 likes I put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we don't have any further condition on $\gamma$, then it's wrong. Let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x^2$. Then for every $a > 0$ the function $$\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\hspace{3mm} x \mapsto \begin{cases}-a & x \in \{a, -a\} \\ x & x \notin \{a, -a\}\end{cases}$$

is such an automorphism. Hence we have infinitely many automorphisms. But $\phi$ isn't periodic, so this is a counterexample.

Comment: Just wondering, if we restrict the bijections to a certain form would it be possible to prove periodicity?